# CSS/Javascript background styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to generate a table like this one (without the balls/pots). The number of rows (y-axe) depends on how many names i have and it can be more or less. The (x-axe) the down number depends on a parameter that i send with the URL as a queryString.I'm new with this and i don't know where and how to start with this, is there a ready template for this?If not can someone please help or give an advice to do something similar?

[image]

Comment: Show some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by background, but if you're looking to do this dynamically (with JS) you'd do it with div's or tables

Comment: `is there a ready template for this?` Not that I'm aware of.  **Advice:** start simple and learn the languages, don't jump right in; learn what to ask (the question is not clear and is causing confusion)

Comment: It could be a table that generates rows dynamically, I can manage this with JS. My problem is that I can't get the styling as what it is in the picture. So in another word it's a table styling @GrahamT

Comment: @Beginner as a said I tried a table but the styling is the problem.

Comment: @SamoZabo So show us your code ^^

Comment: @CitizenDelta 
cshtml: I get a model from an mvc action and then i do the following
`<table class="table-bordered">
@foreach(var name in Model.Names)
{
<tr>name</tr>
}
</table>
`
And the rest of the table I want to generate dynamically to get the columns

In JS I find the id of the name and then i generate the whole row and id could be something like this
`$(this).apped('<td>something something</td>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have made a `jsFiddle` with comments to help you to understand : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x98sfmw1/) (There are no balls and pots, as asked ^^)

The result in image :

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wow, that's generous of you

Comment: @CitizenDelta Dude I realy appreciate that! Thanks alot!!